# Why does creating EC2 key pair using Boto create_key_pair() returns 403:Authentication Failure

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

Here is the attempt I have made and the output(interlaced).

> > > from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
> > >
> > > v = EC2Connection()
> > >
> > > v

EC2Connection:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

> > > v.create_key_pair('somePair')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 2306, in create_key_pair

```
return self.get_object('CreateKeyPair', params, KeyPair, verb='POST')
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1096, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)

boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

`UnauthorizedOperation`You are not authorized 
to perform this operation.43b2cb82-33e4-4294-bf76-387be9c50dc1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489072/python-aws-boto-error?rq=1) thread did the trick for me. 
I was using EC2Connection() without passing it the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key since I had set them up in environ variables. I read it somewhere that this function would pick them up. I wonder how it returned a successful connection. Perhaps, no authentication is done at the point of connecting to aws.